# UI router transition to 404 state when resolve data is not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is a good way to transition to 404 state when you cannot resolve data by state params (state param is invalid or outdated). I currenly do it by throwing exception and handling it in the global event handler:

```
$stateProvider.state('main.tasks.record', {
  url: '/task/{id}',
  resolve: {
    task: function (Tasks, $stateParams) {
      var task = Tasks.findOne($stateParams.id);
      if (!task) {
         throw new Error('Task with id "' + $stateParams.id + '" not found');
      }
    }
  }
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error.message.match('not found')) {
      console.log('Not found error detected', error.message);
      console.log('Redirecting to main state');
      return $state.go('main');
    }

    //all other exceptions - log and rethrow
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('$stateChangeError');
    console.log(arguments);
    throw 'Error while change states: from ' + fromState.name + ' to ' + toState.name;
});
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL router otherwise to route to a catchall state:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/fourOFour');
$stateProvider.state("fourOFour", { url : '/fourOFour'//...});
```